# VBA generated Ajax 7 script won't display a Bing map in my access web browser control

Tags: ajax, vba, ms-access, bing-maps

I'm trying to generate Bing map ajax scripts on the fly depending on user selections in an access form.  I would like to be able to display the map in an Access web browser control.

The problem is that two identical looking htm files act differently.

Good.htm loads in access, IE, firefox and opera fine.

Auto.htm, the one generated by code, opens in opera, firefox with no bugs in firefly, but not in access. It opens in IE but with the pop-up "Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls". When I click the "Allow blocked content" button it loads fine.
It will not load in access, if I put buttons in they will show, but the map won't.

I wrote a program to check both files for any differences in characters, there are none.

I can copy the script from auto.htm and paste it into good.htm and it will still be good.

One thing I did notice though, is that the properties that windows reports for good.htm, oddly, has  "This file came from another computer and might be blocked...". If I click "unblock" then it will no longer work.  auto.htm doesn't have that restriction.

I made good.htm by copying the html from "Bing Maps V7 Interactive SDK" and pasting it into a text file, them changing the extension to .htm.

For what it's worh, here's the script

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"enter code here"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html>
       <head>
          <title>Map view (bounds)</title>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
          var map = null;


          function getMap()
          {
            var boundingBox = Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromString("42.3262, -83.8191, 42.2322, -83.6713");
            map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), 
            {credentials: 'my basic developer key', 
             bounds: boundingBox, 
             heigth: 590, 
             width: 850
            });
          }

          </script>
       </head>
       <body onload="getMap();">
          <div id='myMap' style="position:relative; width:850px; height:590px;"></div>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You could try adding this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you Tim, I didn't know about that. I added "<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->". Now it opens nicely in IE, but still not at all in Access.

Comment: Sorry - that was my one suggestion...  Not too familiar with Access.

Comment: It seems that worked after all.  After some time off that project, when I reopened it the map loaded in Access just fine.

Comment: @TimWilliams After some time elapsed your suggestion worked in Access as well (must be something to do with the IE cache). If you re-post that as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding the "Mark Of the Web":

[Http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx](http://Http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx)